# to show original price and price after discount on cart page when discount is enabled in opencart

Tags: opencart, discount

I want to show original price and price after discount on cart page when discount is enabled in opencart .How to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

In the product form where you add the discount there is an option of start date and end date look at that once.

Another thing is if that product has a special price already then discount price will not enable.